# It is compiling but crashes everytime

Tags: c, char

I'm brand new to programming..im just trying to make my own program to find the volume and surface area of spheres and cylinders. I cant figure out why this program keeps crashing before it will get to the rest of the code. I'm guessing the `char*` might be wrong but i cant see why it would be.

```
int main()
{
    char* solid;
    char* unit;
    printf("Welcome to the Center of Spheres and Cylinders!\n");
    printf("Would you like to look at a Sphere or a Cylinder?: ");
    scanf("%s", solid);
        if(solid == "Cylinder" || solid == "cylinder")
        {
            printf("You chose to look at a Cylinder.\n");

        else if(solid == "Sphere" || solid == "sphere")
        {
            printf("You chose to look at a Sphere.\n");
```

it crashes just after I input for `scanf.`..when i type in either cylinder or sphere it crashes. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`solid` is a character pointer, it is *not* pointing to any *allocated* memory location which is causing your program crash when you try to read data into it with `scanf()` ( and which is why it crashes right after that call as you observe).

After you declare

```
 char *solid;
```

you should `malloc()` a certain amount of storage for it to point to. Alternatively you could have declared an array named `solid`

```
 char solid[100];
```

Note that the crash is actually a good thing in that it is helpful to show there's a problem with an errand pointer. This may not always happen unfortunately depending on where a pointer in memory is pointing too.

Comment: so i decided to declare it as an array and it stopped crashing! but now is just doesnt perform any of the other code... it will take the input from 
scanf("%s", solid);
but the program ends..
thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line

```
if(solid == "Cylinder" || solid == "cylinder")
```

U cannot compare strings like that in  C. Instead use strcmp library function available in C.

The code should be something like below

```
if( (strcmp(solid,"Cylinder")==0) || (strcmp(solid,"cylinder")==0) )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, Levon is right. After the scanf part, you could compare the strings like I said above.

Answer (score 0):

`char* solid;` creates a character pointer that points to an arbitrary location (at least for automatic variables, which is what you have in your code). Then, when you try to `sccanf` into that location, you're invoking undefined behaviour because there is no valid backing storage.

Something like `char solid[100];` *would* create the backing storage, solving that immediate problem, since it allocates space for the characters to be stored. However, there are at least two other problems with your code.

---

The first is that you don't compare strings in C with `==`, that merely compares the pointers, not the content *behind* the pointers. To compare the content, C provides a `strcmp` function so, rather than:

```
if (solid == "something")
```

you should have:

```
if (strcmp (solid, "something") == 0)
```

Some implementations may also provide `stricmp` which ignores case so you don't have to do:

```
if ((strcmp (solid, "something") == 0) || (strcmp (solid, "Something") == 0))
```

instead going with:

```
if (stricmp (solid, "something") == 0)
```

which will allow *any* characters to be upper or lowercase, such as `SomeThing`.

However, that's not standard C so it may not be available everywhere.

---

Your other major problem lies with `scanf("%s")`. Using an unbounded string here is unsafe as you're subject to buffer overflows if the user enters more than you expect. For example, if you use the afore-mentioned `char solid[100]` and the user enters five hundred characters, it's likely to trash your stack and cause yet another crash.

If you want a truly robust user input function, have a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921). It has overflow protection and throws away the rest of the line if necessary so that subsequent inputs are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has several "flaws", as pointed out by the others:

1. The "star" denotes a pointer. A pointer must point to a location in memory, which can be done via malloc(), pointer assignment/manipulation, or explicit bit addresses. For more information on pointers, you can read this: http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm (But seriously, pointers? You've mentioned you're a beginner in programming; pointers are an advanced concept not only in C, but in computer science as well. Anyways, do not think too much about them at the moment.)
2. String comparison in C is not done by the simple equality operator, but via bit comparison (which is automagically done by the  library). The equality operator (==) compares only primitive types (int, char, etc) but not user-defined types or arrays (a string is a character array). You have to use strcmp() (or strncmp() to compare the first n bytes from an optional offset). You can search Google for the documentation of strcmp() and strncmp() for more information.

Keeping these concepts in mind, your program will be like this:

```
#include <string.h> /**Contains string manipulation functions; very important **/
#include <ctype.h> /**Contains tolower() **/
int main()
{
    char* solid;
    char* unit;

    printf("Welcome to the Center of Spheres and Cylinders!\n");
    printf("Would you like to look at a Sphere or a Cylinder?: ");
    scanf("%s", solid);

    if(strcmp(tolower(solid), 'cylinder') == 0)
    {
        printf("You chose to look at a Cylinder.\n");

    else if(strcmp(tolower(solid), 'sphere') == 0)
    {
        printf("You chose to look at a Sphere.\n");

    }
    /** Other code here **/
    return 0;
}
```

As you might have guessed, tolower() turns a string to lowercase. And additional FYI, an array is a pointer, so the justification in using the "star" notation for storing your input from scanf.

Comment: `tolower()` only works on characters. Also the valid syntax for strings is with double quotes `"str"`

Comment: @Yno: thanks for the corrections. Just a carry-over from PHP.